# Mysql query taking long time need to optimize

Tags: mysql, database

this is my query and sales table having almost 18485388 records and evs_MAX_3 having only 29 records but as per my query need to search all records to find out only matching records. but the approach is taking too much time, can anyone suggest me better way on this.

```
create table tmp_e1 as select sale_record_id,
transaction_id,
date(sale_date_time) as date,
sale_amount,
float_account_id,
(float_account_balance_after) as close_Balance,
sale_status_id,'max3' as type from dailyreports.evs_sale 
where sale_record_id in (select 
                         sale_id 
                         from dailyreports.tmp_evs_MAX_3 
                         group by date)
```

Comment: please show us the create of the tables evs_sale and tmp_evs_MAX_3. also a explain from dailyreports.evs_sale where sale_record_id in (select sale_id from dailyreports.tmp_evs_MAX_3 group by date) to see if there a index problem

Comment: Thank you all for the responses, have used joins which is help me to reduce query execution a lot.

Answer (score 1):

(The slow part is the `SELECT`; I have extracted it away from the `CREATE TABLE` to focus on it.)

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is often a slow construct.  The query can be rewritten as

```
select  sale_record_id,
        transaction_id,
        DATE(sale_date_time) as date,
        sale_amount,
        float_account_id,
        float_account_balance_after as close_Balance,
        sale_status_id,
        'max3' as type
    FROM ( SELECT  sale_id
            FROM  dailyreports.tmp_evs_MAX_3
            GROUP BY  date 
         ) AS t
    JOIN  dailyreports.evs_sale  ON sale_record_id = t.sale_id
```

These will probably help:

```
tmp_evs_MAX_3:  INDEX(sale_id, date)
evs_sale:  INDEX(sale_record_id)
```

Note how the `FROM` will get only 29 rows, then the `JOIN` will need to look up only 29(?) rows.  And there are indexes to help each step.

(If you provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN` for the original formulation, we can point out why it is so slow.)

Comment: Hello, @Rick James. Thank you for your help; I made similar modifications using the Join condition, which succeeded, but I'll give this one a go as well.